# How to define src attribute from web application context in JSP

Tags: jsp, absolute-path, contextpath

I wanted to use absolute path in src attribute, while including Javascript and CSS files in JSP.

Using relative URLs would not serve my purpose, similar to the one below :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

If I use absolute URL like,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/appName/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

Then I am hard-coding web application name which is not suitable again...

The best option I found is :

```
<base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"  />
```

But, it only works on href attributes like `<a href="home.jsp" />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got your solution:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.js"></script>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home.jsp">Home</a>
```

or, using the JSTL:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/js/jquery.js"/>"></script>
<a href="<c:url value="/home.jsp"/>">Home</a>
```

The JSTL tag has the added advantage that it also adds the session ID to the URL if cookies are disabled, in order to track session using URL-rewriting.

Comment: Yeah I was able to work first solution but definitely I would prefer the second solution using JSTL you gave. I was looking for something like that only. Thanks.